# Typescript warning

Tags: typescript

Typescript gives the error that `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'string'` in the function getOptionAt below.

If the `text` property is only being accessed when options[ix] is an object, why is it treating it as a string?

```js
type Options = Array<string|{
    text: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}>


let options: Options = [
    "item",
    {
        text: "disabledItem",
        disabled: true
    }
];

function getOptionAt(ix: number) {
    // ERROR: `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'string'`
    return typeof options[ix] === 'object' ? options[ix].text : options[ix];
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to typescript 4.9

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do type guarding on properties when the key is of a wide type like `number`; this issue is being tracked at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  The "standard" workaround is to copy the property to a new variable, which will undergo narrowing as expected... see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/weBMKN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think that affects anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `options[ix]` of `options[ix].text` to a type that contains a `text` property.

```
function getOptionAt(ix: number) {
    return typeof options[ix] === 'object' ? (options[ix] as {text: string}).text : options[ix];
}
```

Comment: You can also do `return typeof options[ix] === 'object' ? options[ix].text : (options[ix] as string)`  to make sure you return the type of value